# AWS resource compatibility across regions with terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

We have an application we deploy with terraform across many AWS regions. Some resource/features are not available across all regions (main problem we encounter is in govcloud regions, where a lot of resources are not supported yet).

We develop on a standard region (us-west-2), so we discover these incompatibility errors only on the multi-regions deployment.

Is anyone familiar with a tool to validate a resource/feature is compatible in all regions ? preferably for terraform, but any automated tool will be appreciated

The use case:
I have a `aws_s3_bucket` terraform resource, and added a new attribute `acceleration_status` for example:

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "my_bucket" {
  bucket              = "my-bucket"
  acceleration_status = "Enabled"

  versioning {
    enabled = true
  }
  .
  .
  .
}
```

This will work on all regions deployment but will fail in `govcloud`.

Optimally I am searching for an automated validation for this level of resource attributes per region. without explicitly stating resources/attributes, but by auto extract it from TF code

Comment: Validate to then do what? Do you only need a list? Or do you want to not provision it?

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary I would like to discover it while developing, so I can apply certain conditions on how to handle this resource creation in regions it is not supported, which vary for each case obviously

Answer (score 0):

You can use `aws ssm get-parameters-by-path` to list *all available services* in a given region.

For example:

*(this is sorted and giving only the first 10 results, for brevity)*

```sh
$ aws ssm get-parameters-by-path \
  --path /aws/service/global-infrastructure/regions/us-east-2/services --output json | \
  jq '.Parameters[].Name' | sort | head -10
```

Or use `boto3`:

```py
resources = boto3.Session().get_available_regions('cloudsearch')
```

to get a list of all the regions where cloudsearch service is available.

Both approaches can be fully automated.

Comment: my need is more terraform specific, and for resources attributes, not general availability of resources. edited the original question with more details

Comment: Well, terraform won't check service availability / resource constraints for you. You have to do this before writing the code. Resources / services vary across regions, and it's your responsibility to verify those. For example, [checking differences between S3 and S3 Govcloud](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/govcloud-us/latest/UserGuide/govcloud-s3.html).